# Using a if in an if with a string check don't work

Tags: php

I do not understand why my if an the if doesn't work. This is my code :

```
 if (isset($_POST['salle'])){
        $idSalle = $_POST['salle'];
        echo('La salle séléctionnée est :' . $idSalle  . '<br />');

        if ($idSalle == "- - - Choisissez  une salle - - - ") {
           /* DO NOT PASS HERE :( */

            $idSalle = "Non séléctionné";
            echo('La salle séléctionnée est :' . $idSalle  . '<br />');
        }

      }
```

But, when I select *- - - Choisissez  une salle - - -* on the checklist, the page respond *"La salle séléctionnée est :- - - Choisissez une salle - - -*" or, logically, the text should be "*La salle séléctionnée est : Non selectionné*".

This is my full code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

      <?php 
      include('fonctionsBDD.php');
      $bdd = connectionBDD(); 

       $idSalle = 0;
       $idUtilisateur = 0;
       $dateDebut = 0;
       $dateFin = 0;
      ?>

      

  
     <!-- Choix des filtres à afficher -->

     <p>Quels filtres afficher ?</p>

    <form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="checkbox" name="cbx-zones">Zones</input> 
      <input type="checkbox" mname="cbx-salles">Salles</input>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cbx-dates">Date</input> 
      <input type="checkbox" name="cbx-heures">Heures</input> 
      <p><input type="submit" /></p>
    </form>

    <!-- Zone filtres -->

    <div class="FiltreSalle">

    <form action="" method="POST">

    <?php 
      if (isset($_POST['cbx-zones'])) {
      /* COntenu d'un filtre ici */
}

    ?>
    <!-- Filtre par Area Name-->

<form action="" method="POST">
    <br /><br />

    <label>Choisir la zone </label><br />

    <select name="zone">
     
    <?php
     echo "      <option unselected>- - - Choisissez  une zone - - - </option>\n";
    $reponseSalle = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM mrbs_area ORDER BY area_name');


     
    while ($donnees = $reponseSalle->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
    ?>

               <option value="<?php echo $donnees->id; ?>"> <?php echo $donnees->area_name; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
     
    ?>
    </select>

    <!-- Filtre par salle -->
       <br /><br />

    <label>Choisir la salle</label><br />

    <select name="salle">
     
    <?php
    
    echo "      <option unselected>- - - Choisissez  une salle - - - </option>\n";
    $reponseSalle = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM mrbs_room ORDER BY room_name');


     
    while ($donnees = $reponseSalle->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
    ?>
               <option value="<?php echo $donnees->id; ?>"> <?php echo $donnees->room_name; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
     
    ?>
    </select>

    <!-- Filtre par utilisateurs-->

    <br /><br />

    <label>Choisir l'utilisateur</label><br />

    <select name="utilisateur">
     
    <?php
     
    echo "      <option unselected>- - - Choisissez  un utilisateur - - - </option>\n";
    $reponseSalle = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM mrbs_users ORDER BY name');


     
    while ($donnees = $reponseSalle->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
    ?>
               <option value="<?php echo $donnees->id; ?>"> <?php echo $donnees->name; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
     
    ?>
    </select>




  <!-- Filtres par DatePicker -->
<br /> <br />
<script>
  $(function() {

    

    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1d",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      dateFormat : '@',
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      dateFormat : '@',
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        var currentDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
 
<label for="from">Du</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">Au</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">



<input type='submit' value='Envoyer'><br /><br />

 </form>


  <!-- Traitement des données -->
 <?php

          /* Une salle seulement */

          if (isset($_POST['salle'])){
            $idSalle = $_POST['salle'];
            echo('La salle séléctionnée est :' . $idSalle  . '<br />');

            var_dump($idSalle);

            if ($idSalle == "- - - Choisissez  une salle - - - ") {
                $idSalle = "Non séléctionné";
                echo('La salle séléctionnée est :' . $idSalle  . '<br />');
            }

          } 
          
         
/*
           $idUtilisateur = $_POST['utilisateur'];
          $dateDebut = $_POST["from"];
          $dateFin = $_POST["to"];
          echo('L utilisateur séléctionné est :' . $idUtilisateur  . '<br />');
          echo('La date de début séléctionnée est :' . $dateDebut  . '<br />');
          echo('La date de fin séléctionnée est :' . $dateFin . '<br />');    */  
  ?>


<!-- Requêtage -->

<?php 

?>
<?php
 /*
  $req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT count(*), ?
    FROM mrbs_entry JOIN mrbs_room  ON mrbs_entry.room_id = mrbs_room.id JOIN mrbs_area ON mrbs_room.area_id = mrbs_area.id
    WHERE mrbs_entry.start_time BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP("'.$datedeb.'") and UNIX_TIMESTAMP("'.$datefin.'")
    or mrbs_entry.end_time BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP("'.$datedeb.'") and UNIX_TIMESTAMP("'.$datefin.'")
    and mrbs_entry.create_by like "'.$nomUtilisateur.'";');


  $req->execute(array());

  while ($donnees = $req->fetch())
  {
    echo '<li>' . $donnees['nom'] . ' (' . $donnees['prix'] . ' EUR)</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';

  $req->closeCursor(); */
  ?>


  </body>
</html>
```

When I add a var_dump($idSalle); here :

```
 /* Une salle seulement */

      if (isset($_POST['salle'])){
        $idSalle = $_POST['salle'];
        echo('La salle séléctionnée est :' . $idSalle  . '<br />');

        var_dump($idSalle);

        if ($idSalle == "- - - Choisissez  une salle - - - ") {
            $idSalle = "Non séléctionné";
            echo('La salle séléctionnée est :' . $idSalle  . '<br />');
        }

      }
```

I got this response : string(32) "- - - Choisissez une salle - - -"

I tried to use trim() like that :

```
      if (isset($_POST['salle'])){
        $idSalle = trim($_POST['salle']);
        echo('La salle séléctionnée est :' . $idSalle  . '<br />');

        var_dump($idSalle);

        if ($idSalle == trim("- - - Choisissez  une salle - - -")) {
            $idSalle = "Non séléctionné";
            echo('La salle séléctionnée est :' . $idSalle  . '<br />');
        }
```

But the result is the same.

So if anyone can help me to understand.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: SHow us `var_dump($idSalle);`

Comment: show full code (HTML form) and remember that `- - - Choisissez  une salle - - - ` is case sensitive and there's a space at the end of it which could be why it's failing or one of the reasons (that space counts).  Use `trim()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, but the result is the same, I have updated my first post

Comment: I tested your code as much as I could and without your db code and it worked, so something else is causing it to fail. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php to see if anything comes of it. I can't replicate the problem. Plus, if the JS you have now is related to it, check your console.

Comment: Hold on. Change all your `- - - Choisissez  une salle - - -` to simply `Choisissez une salle` without the extra spaces and hyphens; that seemed to have worked differently for me. This in your select also. The spaces and hyphens may be doing something really funky.

Comment: You should add walk through trim() $idSalle. Not *""- - - Choisissez  une salle - - -"* string

Comment: @VincentDUPONT I just figured it out. I'll edit my deleted answer. Hold on. Edit: undeleted.

Comment: @VincentDUPONT You state *"But, when I select - - - Choisissez une salle - - - on the checklist, the page respond "La salle séléctionnée est :- - - Choisissez une salle - - -" or, logically, the text should be "La salle séléctionnée est : Non selectionné"."* - which as far as I can see seems to be normal. Try using a `value` for it as I posted in my answer below, and to which I made an edit with the conclusive tests I made and even on an HTML5 compliant browser. What you stated doesn't tell us what you're really expecting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out.

The reason why your conditional statement is failing is because the option has no "value".

Change it to the following:

```
echo "      <option unselected value=\"- - - Choisissez  une salle - - - \">Choisissez une salle</option>\n";
```

So you can remove `trim()` and keep the space in there if you want.

However, you may want to remove the trailing space from it. If you do, you will need to do the same thing for the conditional statement.

---

**Pass** test and using an added `else{...}`

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['salle'])){
        $idSalle = $_POST['salle'];
        echo('La salle séléctionnée est :' . $idSalle  . '<br />');

        if ($idSalle == "- - - Choisissez  une salle - - - ") {
           /* DO NOT PASS HERE :( */

            $idSalle = "Non séléctionné";
            echo('La salle séléctionnée est :' . $idSalle  . '<br />');
        }
         else {
         echo "Xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
         }

      } 



?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <br /><br />

<select name="salle">

    <?php

    echo "      <option unselected value=\"- - - Choisissez  une salle - - - \">Choisissez une salle</option>\n";
    echo "      <option value=\"123\">123</option>\n";
    ?>
    </select>

<input type='submit' value='Envoyer'><br /><br />

 </form>
```

Test - Removed trailing space in `if ($idSalle == "- - - Choisissez  une salle - - -")`

**Fail**  and using an added `else{...}`

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['salle'])){
        $idSalle = $_POST['salle'];
        echo('La salle séléctionnée est :' . $idSalle  . '<br />');

        if ($idSalle == "- - - Choisissez  une salle - - -") {
           /* DO NOT PASS HERE :( */

            $idSalle = "Non séléctionné";
            echo('La salle séléctionnée est :' . $idSalle  . '<br />');
        }
         else {
         echo "Xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
         }

      } 



?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <br /><br />

<select name="salle">

    <?php

    echo "      <option unselected value=\"- - - Choisissez  une salle - - - \">Choisissez une salle</option>\n";
    echo "      <option value=\"123\">123</option>\n";
    ?>
    </select>

<input type='submit' value='Envoyer'><br /><br />

 </form>
```

Even on an HTML5 compliant browser.

Comment: Isn't the `value` optional in html5, as according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option -> `value ... If this attribute is omitted, the value is taken from the text content of the option element.`?

Comment: @Sean It could, however in testing this with an `else{...}` and where  I made the condition failed deliberately, went to the `else{...}`. and I'm on HTML5 too

Comment: @VincentDUPONT That's great Vincent, I'm glad to have been of help, *cheers* and you're welcome.